# Image appear at mouse location

Tags: javascript, html

I am  trying to make an image appear to the location of the mouse coordinates when I click the canvas.

Right now I have it appearing, but I can only figure out how to do it with automatic updating coordinates and the image will follow the mouse after an "onclick".

I need to make it so the image will just move to the location I click, not follow the cursor.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
<title>Click to make a sad face</title>

</head>


<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="2000" height="1000", onClick="makeface();"></canvas>

<script type="text/javascript">
function writeMessage(canvas, message) {
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.font = '18pt Calibri';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fillText(message, 10, 25);
      }

function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
          x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
          y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
      }

      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) 
      {
        var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
        var message = 'Click to make a face appear at coordinates: ' + mousePos.x + ',' + mousePos.y;
        writeMessage(canvas, message);
      }, false);

      function makeface() 
      { 
       canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) 
      {
        var mousePos2 = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
        var headx = mousePos2.x;
        var heady = mousePos2.y;
        var message = 'You made the face appear, you are currently at coordinates: ' + mousePos2.x + ',' + mousePos2.y;
        writeMessage(canvas, message);
        var headrad = 50;
        var smileoffsetx=0;
        var frownoffsety = 33;
        var smilerad=20;
        var eyeoffsety = -10;
        var lefteyeoffsetx = -15;
        var righteyeoffsetx = -lefteyeoffsetx;
        var eyerad = 8;

        ctx.strokeStyle="blue";
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(headx,heady,headrad,0,2*Math.PI,true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.arc(headx+smileoffsetx,heady+frownoffsety,smilerad,-.20*Math.PI,-.80*Math.PI,true);
        ctx.stroke();
            ctx.beginPath()
            ctx.arc(headx+lefteyeoffsetx,heady+eyeoffsety,eyerad,0,2*Math.PI,true);
              ctx.fillStyle="blue";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath()
              ctx.arc(headx+righteyeoffsetx,heady+eyeoffsety,eyerad,0,2*Math.PI,true);
        ctx.fill();
          }, false);
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your writeMessage function is clearing the entire canvas.

This is my quick and dirty fix:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="2000" height="1000" onClick="document.madeFace = 0; makeface();"></canvas>
```

...

```
  function makeface() 
  { 
   canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) 
  {
    var mousePos2 = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    document.madeFace = document.madeFace || mousePos2; /* added */
    var message = 'You made the face appear, you are currently at coordinates: ' + mousePos2.x + ',' + mousePos2.y;
    mousePos2 = document.madeFace; /* added */
    var headx = mousePos2.x;
    var heady = mousePos2.y;
```

...

What this code does is to store the coordinates of the face as soon as the user has clicked. When the user clicks again, the variable "document.madeFace" is reset to 0 and so the coordinates of the face are re-calculated.

But the face is still re-drawn every time the mouse moves, and so it will still appear even though the entire canvas gets cleared.

Comment: It should still appear onclick.  If you use say 200 for headx and 200 for heady, the image will appear until you move it.  Right now I'm just trying to get it to appear at the location of the mouse click before I fix this issue.

Comment: Your original post said you wanted the image to stay in the same place. That is what I fixed for you. Do you also need the problem to be solved of the image appearing on the first movement after the click rather than the click itself?

Comment: It does move the image with every new click. But the image doesn't appear until the first movement after the click, since the drawing function for the image is assigned to the mouse movement event handler rather than the click event.

Comment: It would be preferable to make it show instantly before having to move the mouse.  Do you know a solution to fix that?  Yeah I forgot to add madeface to the onclick.  It works great.

Comment: Yes. Assign the face-drawing function to a local variable, and then add it as a listener to both the click and the move events.

Answer (score 0):

This is what to do to make it happen exactly onclick instead of after onclick.

Put this variable outside of the function:

```
var faceHandler = function(evt) 
  {
    var mousePos2 = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
    document.madeFace = document.madeFace || mousePos2;
```

... until the end of the function, i.e., the curly brace that is now in the line that looks like this:

```
   }, false);
```

Then register the onclick outside the function and the mousemove inside the function:

```
   canvas.addEventListener('click', faceHandler, false);
 function makeface() 
 { 
     canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', faceHandler, false);
 }
```